# Adding a theme to shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I try to follow https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/ to add a certain theme to my shinyUI but it doesn't work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("superhero"),

    titlePanel(""),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 500,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
))
```

I always only receive

> An error has occurred! superhero is not an available theme. Valid
> themes are: .

Comment: All is working for me, try physically deleting the folder or directory where that package is and re-install it

Comment: It is working for me too! Maybe re-install the package or re-launch R (sometimes the problem is that you just to restart R)